# Error clearing /var/cache/de_/ in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, caching

I keep getting this error in Symfony2

> InvalidArgumentException: The file
>   "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bundlename/app/../var/cache/de_/assetic/routing.yml"
>   does not exist.

No amount of the following fixes it

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

I have gotten rid of the error in the past my running these commands over and over again in a last ditch attempt. But it keeps reoccurring and I have no idea why.

Comment: Try running `composer install` ?

Comment: Have you solved your issue ?

Comment: I think it occurred because of a buggy 3rd party Bundle. I removed it and it seemed to go away. But aggressive force removing of var and 777-ing of var was also needed.